# About (Infinite) Discrete Linear Orders Theory

Tags: model-theory

If  $\mathcal{L}$ ={$\leq$}.  A linear order $\mathcal{A}$= (A , $\leq$) is discrete if and only if

I- $\forall$ $a\in A$ there is some $a'\in A$ such that $ a< a'$ then there is a  minimal $b\in A$ which $ a< b$.

II-  $\forall$ $a\in A$ there is some $a'\in A$ such that $ a' < a $ then there is a  maximal $b\in A$ which $ b < a$.

Intuitively, we can identify 4 classes of (infinite) Discrete Linear Orders.  Namely

1-The class of discrete linear orders with a minimal element and without a maximal element. As an example ( $\mathbb{N},\leq$).

2-The class of discrete linear orders with a maximal element and without a minimal element. As an example ( $\mathbb{N}$, something like $\geq$).

3-The class of discrete linear orders with both a maximal element and a minimal element. As an example, one can say the union of two discrete linear orders (A, $\leq$) $\cup$ (B, $\leq$). [ such that the first one is like case 1, and the second one is like case 2.  Plus, for all $a\in A$ and $b\in B$,  $a< b$ ].

4-The class of discrete linear order without endpoints. As an example  ( $\mathbb{Z},\leq$).

How do I write a proof for this intuition? And then show any other arbitrary discrete linear order would necessarily fall into one of these classes.

$\it {Edit 1: }$ I'm not sure about maximal and minimal words, maybe last and least is better. [ Or top and bottom which I saw in a version ].

$\it {Edit 2: }$ Regarding to Alex Kruckman's comments, I modify my question : 
 How can one prove every infinite countable discrete linear order necessarily must be isomorphic to one of these four structures?

Comment: Isn’t this tautological? The fourth case just seems to be equivalent to saying the first three cases don’t hold.

Comment: There are nontrivial statements that sound like this sometimes... like how there are four isomorphism classes of countable dense linear orders. But all this seems to say is either the order has a max and a min, a max but no min, a min but no max, or neither. Which is just a logical case analysis. (I suppose it uses the fact that in an order, max/min are unique if they exist.)

Comment: You say "with a maximal element and without a maximal element" in 2 and "with both a maximal element and a maximal element" in 3. I assume these are typos! But yes, as spaceisdarkgreen says, this is just the fact that any linear order either has a maximal element or doesn't, and either has a minimal element or doesn't...

Comment: @Alex Kruckman, Yes! Those are typos. Thank you. I edited. Maybe I didn't write well. You know what I meant, I meant how can I prove that every infinite countable discrete linear order must be isomorphic to one of these four structures?

Comment: @MaryamAjorlou Actually, I did not know what you meant. There's a big difference between what you wrote in the question (any infinite discrete linear order is in one of those four classes) and what you wrote in your last comment (any *countably* infinite discrete linear order is isomorphic to one of four particular structures). The former is tautologically true, the latter is false.

Comment: For example, $(\mathbb{Z},<)$, $(\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z},<)$, $(\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{Z},<)$, etc. are all examples of countably infinite discrete linear orders no endpoints.

Comment: Dear Alex Kruckman, Okay. let me say what I mean. I had seen a classification for infinite countable dense linear orders. Then I wanted to see how can I write and then prove a parallel question for infinite countable discrete linear orders, and now I feel this classification would be true. And in the next step, I want to say every other example like copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ will fall into one of these four. [ will be isomorphic to one of these four].

Comment: @MaryamAjorlou Again, there's a big difference between "will fall into one of these four (classes)" and "will be isomorphic to one of these four". Do you understand why my previous comment "the former is tautologically true, that latter is false" is true? If you clarify, I'll turn my comments into an answer.

Comment: It was my expression. Roughly speaking, I used it for being isomorphic. I didn't think it may make ambiguity.

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question after receiving an answer (especially one so encompassing and elaborate). Instead you should accept the answer, and ask a new question referring to this one.

Comment: That being said, you cannot. Consider the lexicographic order $I\times\Bbb Z$, where $I$ is *any* countable linear order.  This is a discrete order without endpoints and it is countable. But it is not isomorphic to any of the four (assuming $I$ has more than one point, anyway).

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I didn't make a particular change. I just thought the" title" may need an edit. Yes, I have received my answer before. (Though, I would say I don't know the rules here)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You suggest dividing the infinite discrete linear orders into four classes:

1. Those with a minimal element, but no maximal element.
2. Those with a maximal element, but no minimal element.
3. Those with both a maximal element and a minimal element.
4. Those with neither a maximal element nor a minimal element.

As pointed out by spaceisdarkgreen in the comments, it is a tautology that every discrete linear order falls into one of these four classes: every linear order either has a maximal element or doesn't, and every linear order either has a minimal element or doesn't. This is a complete answer to the original question.

It is *not* a tautology, but also not hard to prove, that these four classes correspond to the four completions of the theory of infinite discrete linear orders. That is, if you take the theory $T$ which says:

- $\leq$ is a linear order
- Every element which is not maximal has an immediate successor.
- Every element which is not minimal has an immediate prececcessor.
- There are at least $n$ elements (one axiom for each natural number $n$).

then adding any one of the axioms defining classes (1) - (4) gives a complete theory. Let's call these theories $T_1$, $T_2$, $T_3$, $T_4$.

You also give a canonical example of a model of each of these theories:

1. $\mathbb{N}$ is a model of $T_1$
2. $\mathbb{N}^*$ (the natural numbers with their reverse order) is a model of $T_2$.
3. $\mathbb{N} + \mathbb{N}^*$ (the natural numbers with their usual order followed by the natural numbers with their reverse order) is a model of $T_3$.
4. $\mathbb{Z}$ is a model of $T_4$.

It turns out that each of these models is the *prime model* of its theory (it admits an elementary embedding into any other model).

From completeness of $T_1$ through $T_4$, and the (tautological) fact that every infinite discrete linear order is in one of your classes 1 through 4, it follows that every infinite discrete linear order is **elementarily equivalent** to one of the four structures $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{N}^*$, $\mathbb{N}+\mathbb{N}^*$, or $\mathbb{Z}$, depending on whether it is a model of $T_1$, $T_2$, $T_3$, or $T_4$.

In the follow-up question, you ask:

> "How can one prove every infinite countable discrete linear order necessarily must be **isomorphic** to one of these four structures?" (emphasis mine)

You cannot prove this, because it is *false*. I gave you counterexamples in the comments. Another way to put it is that none of the theories $T_i$ is countably categorical - this is the contrast with the case of dense linear orders. If you take the theory of dense linear orders and specify whether there is a maximal and/or a minimal element, then you get a complete and countably categorical theory.

Nevertheless, we can obtain a reasonable understanding of the structure of all models of the theories $T_i$. When $L$ and $L'$ are linear orders, by $L+L'$ I mean the disjoint union of $L$ and $L'$, with all the element of $L'$ coming after the elements of $L$. By $L\times L'$, I mean the cartesian product of $L$ and $L'$, with the lexicographic order.

1. Every model of $T_1$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}+L\times \mathbb{Z}$ for some linear order $L$.
2. Every model of $T_2$ is isomorphic to $L\times \mathbb{Z}+\mathbb{N}^*$ for some linear order $L$.
3. Every model of $T_3$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{N}+ L\times \mathbb{Z} + \mathbb{N}^*$ for some linear order $L$.
4. Every model of $T_4$ is isomorphic to $L\times \mathbb{Z}$ for some *non-empty* linear order $L$.

Note that your canonical examples are given by taking $L$ to be empty in cases (1) - (3), and by taking $L$ to be the one-point linear order in case (4).

Note also that whenever $L$ is countable, the resulting model is countable. Since there are continuum-many countable linear orders up to isomorphism, it follows that each of the theories $T_i$ has countinuum-many countable models up to isomorphism. This is as far as possible from your claim that every countably infinite discrete linear order is isomorphic to one of your canonical structures.

Here's a plan for how you can prove the classification: Let $M$ be an infinite discrete linear order. Define a relation $a\sim b$ if and only if $b$ is the successor of $a$. Let $E$ be the reflexive symmetric and transitive closure of $\sim$. Prove that $E$ is an equivalence relation with convex classes. Then the linear order on $M$ naturally orders the $E$-classes as some linear order $L$. Show that the minimal class (if there is one) is ordered like $\mathbb{N}$ and the maximal class (if there is one) is ordered like $\mathbb{N}^*$, and every other class is ordered like $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you very much!  How perfect and deep the answer was.

Comment: Specifically, that paragraph you make $L\times\mathbb{Z}$ and put it after, before and between $\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{N^*}$, $\mathbb{N+\mathbb{N^*}}$, respectively.

Comment: Nice! When you start talking about models in general, I guess that you're taking the view that a model must not be empty, which is why $L$ must be non-empty in case (4) (and why the prime model for that case is $\mathbb Z$ rather than $\varnothing$). (Of course, that model is ruled out in the original question, which asked about *infinite* orders.)

Comment: @TobyBartels I'm happy to allow empty models. But note that I included axioms saying that there are infinitely many elements! There's a good reason to restrict to infinite linear orders here: if a complete theory has any finite model, then it only has one model up to isomorphism.

Comment: Never mind, I missed that you wrote into the theory that the structure is infinite. (ETA: And you already made a comment about this!)

Comment: (And if you hadn't put those axioms into the theory, then there would also be finite models of $T_3$, which would have clued me in that I was missing something if I had noticed them the first time.)